# python3 tkinter gui not reacting on execution

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, python-3.5

I'm using tkinter for my python3 GUI. The script I wrote, when executing in IDLE. But when I try to execute it without the GUI is not responding.

Here's the code:

```
#! python3

from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

class Program:

    nameC  = ""
    master = ""
    varC   = ""

    def callback(self):  
        self.nameC= filedialog.askopenfilename()

    def __init__(self):
        self.master = Tk()
        self.varC = StringVar(self.master)

        l1 = Label(text="Open file", relief=RIDGE,width=15)
        l1.grid(row=0,column=0)
        b1 = Button(text='Open', command=self.callback)
        b1.grid(row=0,column=1)


program = Program()
mainloop()
```

So far I have a button and a label. If I click on the button, a filedialog is opened using the callback function

EDIT: fixed one error in the code
If it helps, I'm using windows

Comment: The indentation looks incorrect

Comment: What do you mean by "execute it without the GUI"?  Is 'it' your entire script or the tkinter part?  Is 'the GUI' IDLE or your tkinter code?

Comment: Please post code that runs.  Even after fixing indents, there is  NameError and will be AttibuteError when that is fixed.

Comment: I fixed the code, but there was no problem with indentation for me. Could you further explain ?  My Issue is, when executing the code in IDLE IDE I get a file choose dialog, when clicking on the button. But when I execute the script just by clicking the .py file the GUI appears but the button does not react

Comment: run it manually in console/terminal (not in IDLE) and you see error - you have to import `filedialog`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after running the script in the console ( as mentioned not IDLE) I figured out that I would have to import filedialog:

```
#! python3

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog # this is what I needed
import tkinter as tk

class Program:

   nameC  = ""
   master = ""
   varC   = ""

   def callback(self):  
       self.nameC= filedialog.askopenfilename()

   def __init__(self):
       self.master = Tk()
       self.varC = StringVar(self.master)

       l1 = Label(text="Open file", relief=RIDGE,width=15)
       l1.grid(row=0,column=0)
       b1 = Button(text='Open', command=self.callback)
       b1.grid(row=0,column=1)


program = Program()
mainloop()
```